# Flattening npm_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 app with an npm_modules folder in it. Each NPM module brings its own dependencies into its folder -- of course each dependency repeats this behavior and we end up with a gazillion levels of subfolders which create a problem on Windows when publishing the app -- the infamous path too long error.

I understand that the new version of NPM uses a flat folder approach. How do I fix this issue on my existing ASP.NET Core app which still has folders within folders for package dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the `node_modules` folder in your current project directory and then do an `npm install`. This will download all of your package dependencies again while using the new flattened dependency structure of NPM v3.

Comment: While this definitely worked and completely flattened the NPM modules installed in my app, I'm still getting that annoying "path too long" error while publishing my app to Azure.